# How to add root node in JSON for every object?

Tags: json, typescript, firebase

I convert excel file to JSON , to import it into my firebase DB.
On conversion, I have the JSON data in below format

```
[
        {
            "ProductNumber": "7381581",
            "SKU": "test3",

        },
        {
            "ProductNumber": "7381582",
            "SKU": "test",
        },
        {..}
    ]
```

But I need it like this

```
{
    "7381581" :{
        "ProductNumber": "7381581",
        "SKU": "test3",

    },
    "7381582":{
        "ProductNumber": "7381582",
        "SKU": "test",


    },{..}
    }
```

How can I make changes to the spreadsheet records to get the JSON in the above format ? (OR)
How should I add the key values to JSON dynamically?

Comment: The first example is invalid syntax. If fixed, have a look at [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reduce as suggested to iterate over the original array and transform it into an object.

```js
data.reduce((prev, current) => {
    prev[current.ProductNumber] = current;
    return prev;
}, {});
```

You can see a working example in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ProductNumber%22%3A%20%227381581%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22SKU%22%3A%20%22test3%22%2C%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22ProductNumber%22%3A%20%227381582%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22SKU%22%3A%20%22test%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%5D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Adata.reduce((prev%2C%20current)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prev%5Bcurrent.ProductNumber%5D%20%3D%20current%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20prev%3B%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%7B%7D)%3B).